# Pandas DataFrame KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

First things first, here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

headers = ["Category", "Brand", "Product_Name", "Shipping", "Price"]

xl = pd.ExcelFile("C:\\Users\\*myusername*\\Desktop\\products.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("products")
print(df)

df = df.sort_values(by=headers[4], axis='columns', na_position='last')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\*myusername*\\Desktop\\output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", columns=headers, index=False)
writer.save()

print("Done")
```

What I'm trying to do with this is sort some data I scraped from Newegg as a sort of practice project. I intend to take this code here and expand it out to do a variety of things with the data, but I thought I'd start easy and just sort it all by the Price column.

When I run the above code, it throws the following error:

```
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mmiller3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4421, in sort_values
    stacklevel=stacklevel)
  File "C:\Users\mmiller3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1382, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Price'
```

When I print(df), immediately after I create it from the parsed xl sheet, it correctly displays the 5 headers, and all the data held within. The header 'Price' definitely exists.

print(df) output below:

```
            Category           Brand   ...     Shipping Costs   Price 
0      Desktop Memory         G.SKILL   ...      Free Shipping  199.99 
1      Desktop Memory         G.SKILL   ...      Free Shipping  143.99
```

That's only a small snippet of the output, it goes on for 147 rows.

I've tried a number of things, including replacing "headers[4]" with a more straight forward "Price", I've tried indicating "E" for the column, rather than using the header.

At this point I'm stumped, and the only other reference I've found to this specific issue was a simple syntax error, but I'm not making that same error.

Any help you guys can offer me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
df = xl.parse("products", names = headers)
```

Comment: I still get the same error after making that addition. (Sorry for the delayed response, I'm working on this stuff in my spare time, and things got a little crazy at work for a few days.)